# Show html data from a JS Table in a <h2/> title

Tags: javascript, java, html, get, getelementbyid

I have a JS table generated by the data entered in textareas by users on my web site (so the data is not there when you first load the page: your have to enter something in the textarea and then generate the table). Now I'm trying to get that data (from the generated table) and show it in a (h2/) for exemple.

**So I made a script to get that information:**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonTEST()
    {
        document.getElementById('excel_table1').getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].cells[1].innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

**and a Button to use that script:**

```html
<input id=GetTest type="button" onclick="buttonTEST()" value="TEST ME"/>
```

When I enter the "document.getElementById....etc" in the console, it shows the data that I want so I think the script is fine.

But how can I get it to SHOW that data (alphanumeric) in a (h2) plain text?

Can someone help? :)

**EDIT! *I tried this:***

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">function buttonTEST(){document.getElementById("yourID").innerHTML="document.getElementById('excel_table1').getElementsByTagName('tr'). 
[0].cells[1]";
}
</script>

<h2 id="yourID"></h2>
<input id="anotherID" type="button" onclick="buttonTEST()" value="TEST ME"/>

</div>
```

But when I click, I just get **"document.getElementById('excel_table1').getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].cells[1]"** as a H2.

Comment: Is something preventing you from doing a `document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = 'the content you want'`?

Comment: @vhoyer, I probably just don't know how to properly use it, but I tried that, and replacing the "content you want" by "document.getElementById('excel_table1').getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].cells[1].innerHTML" which is the cell that I want to display as a h2, but it didn't work. I think i'm not properly "showing the way" to that cell, in my script. Is that it?

Comment: well, accessing the [w3schools page for tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) and running this on the console: `document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById('customers').getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].cells[0].innerHTML` executes the described desired behavior for me, can you try and tell me if it works for you?

Comment: Yes, I got "Company" (in red) back from the w3schools page for tables. But actually, when I run "document.getElementById('excel_table1').getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].cells[1].innerHTML;" on the console of my page, it gets too the right data that I want. The problem is to display it on a h2 !

Comment: Then, can you edit your question to add more information about the `h2` on the page and the way you are tring to assign the value to the said `h2`? I think this will help us help you better :D

Comment: @vhoyer Thanks, I just edited my question with more details, what I've tried since that didn't work and the result I got back from that! I hope it's a little clearer :D

Comment: @vhoyer I found the solution. I'm sorry; i'm new here, is there a "solved" button on this forum, or am I supposed to do anything after the answer is found?

Comment: yeah, sure, to make a mark the question as "solved" you need to choose an answer as the solution, there should be a check mark below the rate arrows, click it to mark the answer as the correct one :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved it ! Thanks everybody for putting me in the right track :D

So, what worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function buttonTEST()
     {
document.getElementById('yourID').innerHTML=document.getElementById('excel_table1').getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].cells[1].innerHTML;
}
</script>

<h2 id="yourID"></h2>
<input id="anotherID" type="button" onclick="buttonTEST()" value="TEST ME"/>

</div>
```

@vhoyer was right, I needed to take off the extra **"** otherwise JS thinks that I want to litteraly write that piece of code to the h2 output.

And the other think is that I needed to put ".innerHTML" again after all my tr and cells (yes, it makes a .innerHTML inside another .innerHTML xD )

Hope that might help someone!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case, seems to be the extra `"` around your expression to get the value.

If a value is already a string, you don't need to wrap it in quotes, since doing so makes javascript think that you want to litteraly write that piece of code to the h2 output

```html
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function buttonTEST() {
  document.getElementById("yourID").innerHTML = document.getElementById('excel_table1').getElementsByTagName('tr').
[0].cells[1].innerHTML;
}
</script>

<h2 id="yourID"></h2>
<input id="anotherID" type="button" onclick="buttonTEST()" value="TEST ME"/>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I just saw that too! So when I execute document.getElementById("yourID").innerHTML=document.getElementById('excel_table1').getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].cells[1]; in the console, the result (the data from the cell) appear on the console. But i get [object HTMLTableCellElement] on the h2 area ...

Comment: I just corrected that, we forgot to add at the end of the `cells[1]` the `.innerHTML` so we take only the innerHTML as a string and not the hole element (like we were doing before)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `<h2>` element in your html file to replace its value (which should be empty in your html file) using javascript.

Make sure you have assigned that `<h2>` an id.

Then, using document.getElementById, access it in your script and change it.

An example below.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 id="yourID"></h2>
    <input id="anotherID" type="button" onclick="buttonTest()" value="TEST ME"/>
    <script>
      function buttonTest() {
        //Grab the ID and change it
        document.getElementById("yourID").innerHTML = "whatever you want it to display";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, make sure to surround the html attributes' values in single or double quotes.

## Edit:

Here is an example for your use case:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>title</title>
 </head>

 <body>
   <h2 id="yourID"></h2>
   <input id="anotherID" type="button" onclick="buttonTest()" value="TEST ME" />
   <p>Press me to find out the second cell in the second row</p>
   <table id="table">
     <tr>
       <th>Color</th>
       <th>Object</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Red</td>
       <td>Poppy</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   <script>
     function buttonTest() {
       //Here we grab the value of the second cell in the second row in a variable called value. You can change the row and cell index to access specific values.
       var value = document.getElementById("table").rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;
       //Then we display it
       document.getElementById("yourID").innerHTML = value;
     }
   </script>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help little monkey! I tried that, but how can I access the data from my table: ('excel_table1') first row: ('tr')[0] second cell: cells[1].innerHTML? I tried putting document.getElementById('excel_table1').getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].cells[1].innerHTML where you wrote "whatever you want it to display" but it didn't work ...

Comment: Try the example I've added. You can change the index values of the rows collection and the cells collection to get different values.